# Magento: all products suddenly out of stock after re-indexing

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento site with around 500 products, and a couple of times over the last year I've seen all of them suddenly and inexplicably go out of stock. I believe this has happened just after we have re-indexed some of the indexes (from the shell).

I run a full re-index procedure and the stock returns to normal.

But there is still a period of "downtime" for the site which is undesirable.

Can anyone explain why this might be happening, and what I can do to avoid it? Additionally, how often should I be re-indexing, ideally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We re index using indexer.php in the shell folder using a cronjob at 3am on a daily basis with no changes to the database. If we are changing items / categories . etc we will re index right after all changes are made.